# Easy way to fill object's fields

Tags: java

I have many servlets like this:

```
public class DoSmthServlet extends AbstractDTOServlet<DoSmthServlet.Params> {

    @Override
    public Response service(Params params) throws Exception {
        // Some logic...

        Response response = new Response();
        response.field1 = data1;
        response.field2 = data2;
        // ...
        return response;
    }

    public static class Params implements DomainDTO {
        public long arg1;
        public boolean arg2;
        // ...
    }

    public static class Response implements DomainDTO {
        public String field1;
        public long field2;
        // ...
    }

}
```

I need to fill Response object with data, but it can contain really many fields. **How to do it without writing many `response.fieldN = dataN` in each servlet?** I don't want to write constructors for each class because I'll still have to write such assignments in constructors.

Maybe there is any library that can do it, or any pattern that I can use, or any way to generate constructors for Response classes?

Comment: Where are you getting data1, data2 etc from?

Comment: @Naman Gala They are declared in method `service`. They are result of doing 'some logic' with params.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by writing this kind of servlet? If you want to develop a restful api, you may want to check other java apis like jax-rs. By using jax-rs you can easily map your Post or Form parameters to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Dozer bean mapper](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html) can help you. Some example:

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

DestinationObject destObject = 
mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);
```

or

```
DestinationObject destObject = new DestinationObject();
mapper.map(sourceObject, destObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any library that can do it for you. But... you can use *fluent builder* which will simplify `Response` creation and make it a little bit... easier I think.

ex.

```
public class ResponseBuilder {
   private Response response = new Response();
   public ResponseBuilder withField1(String field1) {
      response.field1 = field1;
      return this;
   }
   public ResponseBuilder withField2(String field2) {
      response.field2 = field2;
      return this;
   }
   public Response build() {
      return response;
   }
}

// usage
Response response = Response.builder.withField1("a").withField2("b").build();
```

BTW: I would rather avoid writing constructor with many arguments for a Value Object/DTO class, because every argument passed to constructor should be considered as required.

Comment: I thought about it. But as far as I understand, it's impossible to do one universal Builder for all Responses. And writing new Builder for each class is hard. Using many assignments is even easier.

Comment: @VladShevchenko : It all depends on your requirements. The question is whether you would like to introduce new dependency (and take another technical debt) or write builders on your own and after 2nd or 3rd see if there is a possibility to improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If number of fields are same for all the `Response` object then write one `static function` and call it from different servlets. `static function` will do all `response.fieldN = dataN`

Comment: No, number and types of fields are different for each Response.